# Sharepoint 2013 Contacts list vacation value from another list based on contact name filter

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, contacts

The firt list is a contacts list for employees where is basic information about him/her. The second list is a automatically syncing vacation info list from HRM software. The list contains columns: row, Name, Planned vac start, Planned vac end, Real vac start, Real vac end.
We would need to the vacation info showing automatically under the contact form based on filter Name.
How can that be achieved?

Comment: From your question I am assuming that you want to join two lists which will be worked as linked. You can use this blog [post](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/01/13/link-two-lists-and-display-the-data-using-the-sharepoint-data-view-aspx/) to achieve this goal.

Comment: Lookup field for Contacts list would be perfect but it cannot be filtered.